What choice do I have July 2025 when support for 24.10 version expires?
I was using Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and got a choice to upgrade to 24.10. I thought the 24.10 was an upgrade to 24.04.1 so I went along and accepted the upgrade. I learned later that 24.10 is supported until July 2025.
I wouldn't have upgraded if I knew the support is not long lasting. I am not knwolegeable enough to know when to go along and when not. The screen pop-up never mentioned that the support will end in July 2025. I am more comfortable with running an LTS version.
So the question is what do I do July 2025? Do I go back to 24.04.1? Do I wait for whatever may come along in July 2025?...
Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Read up on the Ubuntu release cycle.  Basically, keep upgrading every 6 months until you get to the next LTS release (April of an even year).  So, April 2026.

"I am not knwolegeable enough to know when to go along and when not." Ubuntu rewards users who are willing to learn.

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS normal upgrades will upgrade you thru 24.04.1, 24.04.2, 24.04.3 etc.., in fact you'll find you're using the next point release late in the week before the actual release of the point release (as point release relates mostly to new media provided for new installs; ie. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/08/30/ubuntu-24-04-1-lts-released/ says "As usual, this point release includes many updates and updated installation media has been provided so that fewer updates will need to be downloaded after installation."

You've (by release-upgrading to 24.10) joined the progress on the next 26.04 LTS; as three interim or progress releases are made in the two year development cycle for 26.04, ie. 24.10, 25.04 & 25.10 show progress before the final polish and release of 26.04 LTS. Your upgrade path is now thru those releases; ie. 25.04 next, six(-nine) months later to 25.10 then to 26.04 LTS, upgrading to that next LTS a couple of months earlier than the upgrade opening from 24.04 to 26.04.1 as you achieved that in little steps rather than one large step.  You can restore backups & return to 24.04 too

First, third and fourth comments are very useful and will help a lot of people in my situation. I think the question should not be deleted or closed.
